# Please Explain Segmentation Fault in this Particular Code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to coding, and so naturally I frequently experience coding errors. I run into segmentation fault errors all the time, and was wondering if anyone could explain what it is, what is wrong with the code below, and how to avoid segmentation faults in the future. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > pointers;
  std::vector<int> squawkers;
  int n, m, s, t, counter = 0;
  std::cin >> n >> m >> s >> t;
  squawkers[s] = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    pointers[a].push_back(b);
    pointers[b].push_back(a);
  }
  while (counter < t) {
    t++;
    std::vector<int> temp (n);
    std::fill(temp.begin(), temp.begin()+n-1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (pointers[i].size() != 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pointers.size(); j++)
          temp[j] += squawkers[i];
      }
    }
    squawkers = temp;
  }
  int sum;
  for (int i = 0; i < squawkers.size(); i++)
    sum += squawkers[i];
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you use your debugger?

Comment: Your vectors `squawkers` and `pointers` are empty and you're trying to access elements that don't exist. Just like in your last SO question...

Comment: What is your intention with the line `squawkers[s] = 1;`?

Comment: `squarkers` has size zero (i.e. `squarkers.size()` returns zero) so the first line `squarkers[s] = 1` has undefined behaviour.  For `squarkers[s] = 1` to be well-defined, the test `s >= 0 && s < squarkers.size()` must be true BEFORE doing it (after is too late).   To make it true, `squarkers` needs to be resized to a value larger than `s` (e.g. by explicitly resizing, or by appending enough elements).   None of that happens unless YOU explicitly make it happen.

Comment: Sorry about that guys. I'll try to be more frugal with questions in the future. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

This short code extracted from your code above is in error.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> squawkers;
  std::cin >> s;
  squawkers[s] = 1;
}
```

It doesn't matter what value `s` has, `squawkers` is size zero and so *any* use of `[]` on it is an error.

For a beginner the rest of your code is quite advanced. So it's strange to me that this simple error exists.

Comment: The first `for` loop has the same problem. They're calling `push_back` on non-existent elements of `pointers`.